# What is the difference and usage of the <i>,<em>,<strong>,<b> tags?

Tags: html

I'm aware there are similar questions, but the key word is similar all these are related and I didnt see a question that explains them in a single place. I'm curious as to what the a semantic use is for each and I'm hoping for some a example, as reading the mdn has left me a bit confused. Also the mdn says the b tag is basically used to style, so I assuming using this tag is bad practice, yet html5 seems to support it, why is this?

```
<i>html</i>
<strong>html</strong>
<em>html</em>
<b>html</b>
```

Comment: Can you clarify how the above duplicate is insufficiently answering your question, if so?

Comment: thanks, I didn't see that one, but I still dont feel like a got good answer from most of those answers I read. They all seem to say broadly that em and strong are for semantic importance but they really dont define that that means. I feel could mean multiple different things. Also they dont really define the difference between the, and they do it seems to be conflicting definitions, example strong is for importance and em is for emphasis, but the definition of emphasis is conveying importance, so I dont feel as if thats a valid difference.

Comment: The first answer explains it quite well: semantic meaning is important for anything that's not visual, like screen readers for the blind, and algorithms analysing the *meaning* of text. `<b>` visually styles an element "with more ink", but a `<strong>` element will be pronounced with more force in a screen reader.

Comment: for the bold tag some say it has semantic meaning but fail to define that meaning and others say its has no semantic meaning and its simply for making things bold but mixing styling with html is bad practice and html5 supports b, so I have some doubts its for styling, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Well, the definition is evolving and is muddled due to historical baggage, but the current definition is: *"The `b` element represents a span of text to which attention is being drawn for utilitarian purposes without conveying any extra importance and with no implication of an alternate voice or mood [...]"*.

Comment: My current understanding is bold just makes things bold like css, so I probably shoudnt use it and strong and emphasis add semantic meaning for screen readers and other devices correct?

Comment: Pretty much, yes. I wouldn't know where to use `b` except as a shorthand for inline CSS either.